How to properly configure HAProxy in Docker Swarm to automatically route traffic to replicated services?
i'm trying to deploy a docker swarm of two host nodes and two host manager with a single replicated service and put an haproxy in front of it. i want the clients to be able to connect via port 80.
My docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  haproxy:
    image: haproxy:latest
    ports:
      - 81:80
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy.cfg:/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
    networks:
      - cluster
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
  apache:
    image: httpd
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
          constraints: [node.role == worker]
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - cluster
    volumes:
      - stack_myvol:/var/www/html/

networks:
  cluster:

volumes:
  stack_myvol:

My haproxy.cfg
global
  log /dev/log local0
  log /dev/log local1 notice
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
  stats timeout 30s
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon

defaults
  log global
  mode http
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 50000
  timeout server 50000

frontend http-in
  bind 172.20.120.131:81
  default_backend apache-servers

backend apache-servers
  #balance leastconn
  balance roundrobin
  server node1 172.20.120.4:80 check
  server node2 172.20.120.5:80 check

The way I'm trying to make this work at the moment is to ssh into the manager node (which also has a static and public IP), copy over my configuration files from above, and run:

docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml apache-stack

url: 172.20.120.131:81
unable to connect

Docker swarms  ingress network already implements a load balancer.  Putting HAProxy inside the swarm adds a largely useless level of indirection. If you want HA routing to services in swarm, from outside swarm, use keepalived on two or more docker nodes and associate that with a VIP mapped to a dns entry.
